# How to check for a nullable value in DateTime initialized variable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

There are two main issues :

1. The initialization of DateTime variable is not allowed
2. The ternary check for a dateTime variable once randomly initialized by Date.now() still cant check for null value.

[The error in DateTime variable assigning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZyVJ.jpg)

[After initialization of DateTime variable with Date.now()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95WHk.jpg)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function transactionAddHandler;

  NewTransaction(this.transactionAddHandler);

  @override
  _NewTransactionState createState() => _NewTransactionState();
}

class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _amountController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime _selectedDate;

  void _submitData() {
    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredAmount = double.parse(_amountController.text);
    if (enteredAmount <= 0 || enteredTitle.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    widget.transactionAddHandler(enteredTitle, enteredAmount);

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _presentDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2021),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    ).then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }

      setState(() {
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
              controller: _titleController,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: _amountController,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 70,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    _selectedDate == null
                        ? 'No Date Chosen!'
                        : DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    child: Text(
                      'Choose Date',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: _presentDatePicker,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _submitData,
              child: Text(
                'Add Transaction',
              ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Do help me and the flutter community grow better. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The _selectedDate is nullable. So mark the variable as,

```dart
DateTime? _selectedDate;
```

And before using it have to check for null first,

```dart
Text(_selectedDate == null
     ? 'No Date Chosen!'
     : DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate!),
    ),
```

Helpful Links->

1. [Null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)
2. [Promotion Failure](https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons#property-or-this)

Answer (score 5):

If `_selectedDate` property does not have a default value, make it nullable:

```
class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  ...
  DateTime? _selectedDate;

  ...
}
```

Comment: I still encounter the error. The old error of initialization is solved but a new one arose. When i use the variable to format using intl package, it throws an error pointing out -
The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'

Comment: You need to check if the variable is null before using it. If you indeed are SURE that this won't be null at the time you are using it, you can use the bang operator: `_selectedDate!`. I would recommend you to lear more about null safety in Dart: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare the variable like: `DateTime? _selectedDate;`
2. If you get the error `The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'` then assign like:

```
Text(
    _selectedDate == null
        ? 'No Date Chosen!'
        : DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate ?? DateTime.now()),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean variable to check if isDateSelected or not:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class NewTransaction extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function transactionAddHandler;

  NewTransaction(this.transactionAddHandler);

  @override
  _NewTransactionState createState() => _NewTransactionState();
}

class _NewTransactionState extends State<NewTransaction> {
  final _titleController = TextEditingController();
  final _amountController = TextEditingController();
  late DateTime _selectedDate;
  bool _isDateSelected = false;

  void _submitData() {
    final enteredTitle = _titleController.text;
    final enteredAmount = double.parse(_amountController.text);
    if (enteredAmount <= 0 || enteredTitle.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }
    widget.transactionAddHandler(enteredTitle, enteredAmount);

    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  void _presentDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2021),
      lastDate: DateTime.now(),
    ).then((pickedDate) {
      if (pickedDate == null) {
        return;
      }

      setState(() {
        _isDateSelected = true;
        _selectedDate = pickedDate;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
              controller: _titleController,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Amount'),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: _amountController,
              onSubmitted: (_) => _submitData(),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 70,
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    !_isDateSelected
                        ? 'No Date Chosen!'
                        : DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    child: Text(
                      'Choose Date',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: _presentDatePicker,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _submitData,
              child: Text(
                'Add Transaction',
              ),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `DateTime _selectedaDate`; to `String _ selectedate=""`;

Where `_selectedDate = pickedDate;`
change to `_selectedDate = pickedDate.toString();`

Any time u need `_selectedDate` in `DateTime` use this:  `DateTime.parse(_selectedDate)`.

Answer (score 0):

If _selectedDate property does not have a default value, make it nullable

`late DateTime? _selectedDate = null;`

and then you can use like this

```
 `Text(_selectedDate == null
     ? "Date is not selected yet      "
     : DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate!))`,
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make the '_selectedDate' variable nullable by defining it like this, `DateTime? _selectedDate;`.

Secondly, the nullability checking condition you put,

```
_selectedDate == null
    ? 'No Date Chosen!'
    : DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate),
```

simply is not enough, additionally put another null check by placing an exclamation mark next to '_selectedDate', like this,

```
_selectedDate == null
    ? 'No Date Chosen!'
    : DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate!),
```

I hope it helps!